# Instantiating generic class

Tags: java, list, generics, skip-lists

I'm trying to implement a SkipList using generics and I have run into a problem. I can't seem to instantiate a node.

Node class:

```
public class SkipNode<E> 
{
    private E key;
    private Integer value;

    //Links
    private SkipNode<E> up, down, left, right;

    //Head and tail keys. Cannot add before -oo or after +oo.
    public static String negInf = "-oo";
    public static String posInf = "+oo";

    public SkipNode() {}

    public SkipNode(E k, Integer v)
    {
        key = k;                                // Add key
        value = v;                              // Assign value

        up = down = left = right = null;        // Set links to null
    }

    //Getters and setters down here
}
```

List class:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SkipList<E>
{
    private SkipNode<E> head;
    private SkipNode<E> tail;

    private int size, height;
    private Random rand;

    public SkipList()
    {
        SkipNode<E> p1, p2;

        p1 = new SkipNode<E>(SkipNode.negInf, null);
    }
}
```

The error is on `p1 = new SkipNode<E>(SkipNode.negInf, null);` I tried removing the `<E>` on that line and changing it to this: `p1 = new SkipNode(SkipNode<E>.negInf, null);`, which doesn't make much sense but I thought I would try it. I also tried doing "-oo" in the parameter but it wants me to change the Node constructor parameters to String and Integer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a concrete type when initializing the class

```
SkipNode<String> p1 = new SkipNode<String>(SkipNode.negInf, null);
```

Comment: Thanks, can you answer the question in my other comment as well, please?

Comment: The question from OP: Do I have to do it like this every time I want to add something to the list? What if I don't know the data type being passed through?

Comment: @yayu `SkipNode` is generic so you have to define the type at implementation time.

Comment: @Reimeus Oh right! Can't believe I forgot that. Thank you both for the help!